# 'SP is not defined' when trying to run JS code on Modern Script Editor

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Im facing this error message, referring to this line:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', CheckCurrentUerGroup);
```

I am quite new to this stuff but what is causing this? I want to use a basic redirecting mechanism using this code:

```
<script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("test");

});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('2nd');
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {
alert('IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup');
        var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
console.log(currentContext );
    var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

    var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
console.log(currentUser);

    currentContext.load(currentUser);

    var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
    currentContext.load(allGroups);

    var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
    currentContext.load(group);

    var groupUsers = group.get_users();
    currentContext.load(groupUsers);

    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

    function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
        var userInGroup = false;
        var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
        while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
            if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                userInGroup = true;
                break;
            }
        }  
        OnComplete(userInGroup);
    }

    function OnFailure(sender, args) {
        OnComplete(false);
    }    
}

function CheckCurrentUerGroup() 
{
alert('checkcurrentuergroup');
  IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("IT Department", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) 
{
if(isCurrentUserInGroup)
{
    //Redirect to a certain page
    window.location = "httpd://www.youtube.com";
}
  });

}
//$(document).ready(function() {
//CheckCurrentUerGroup();
//
//});

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', CheckCurrentUerGroup);


</script>
```

Comment: using code of: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130971/get-user-from-sharepoint-group-and-redirect

Answer (score 2):

try this:

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CheckCurrentUerGroup, "sp.js");

Answer (score 0):

Test demo:

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?name=sp.res&culture=en-us"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/SP.Core.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>    
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {
        alert('IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup');
        var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        console.log(currentContext);
        var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

        var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        console.log(currentUser);

        currentContext.load(currentUser);

        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
        currentContext.load(allGroups);

        var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
        currentContext.load(group);

        var groupUsers = group.get_users();
        currentContext.load(groupUsers);

        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess, OnFailure);
        debugger;
        function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
            debugger;
            var userInGroup = false;
            var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
            while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
                if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                    userInGroup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            OnComplete(userInGroup);
        }

        function OnFailure(sender, args) {
            debugger;
            OnComplete(false);
        }
    }

    function CheckCurrentUerGroup() {            
        alert('checkcurrentuergroup');
        IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("App Dev Members", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
            if (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
                //Redirect to a certain page
                window.location = "https://www.youtube.com";
            }
        });

    }
    //$(document).ready(function() {
    //CheckCurrentUerGroup();
    //
    //});        
    //SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', CheckCurrentUerGroup);
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CheckCurrentUerGroup, "sp.js");
</script>
```

[image]